# How to report Performance merics/ Non Physical resources in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I'm looking for a way to report NFR/performance quality metrics of a code, these metrics comes from the execution of unit tests and can be for example the average, minimum and maximum response times statistics, number of executions and other custom metrics.

For this, i'm thinking to create "virtual" resources that are not liked to sources on each class and test method, and report these metrics on them so that every time the tests are executed i get an idea on the impact of the last changes on performance.

I saw in other discussion that SonarQube is designed for static code quality, these  performance and NFR metrics are also part of the code quality, i think it makes sense that they get reported and tracked in SonarQube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as you noted, SonarQube is designed for static code analysis, you're going to have a hard time with the 'virtual' resources route. Analysis looks at the directories and files in the source directory. No file, no SonarQube resource, and nowhere to attach metrics.

If you're determined to do this, then you should consider attaching your metrics at some aggregate level: module or project. Note that metric history isn't kept below the project level.

Alternately, you could attach these metrics to the test files themselves.

Comment: Attaching the metrics to the class themselves has a limitation, if I have two test methods in a class that tests a web service, one is calling a search and the other is calling another operation I’ll not be able to report the performance of each operation. Making manual measures is doable but will generate too match metrics if I need to track all functional tests!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the historical data is another point, as last option I will keep the methods level metrics in a separate repository and write a SonarQube widget that displays these metrics, I made a prototype and that worked, used w2ui, I will lose SonarQube capability but for a first approach that will be fine